# CakePHP: Cannot redeclare class AppModel in models.php

Tags: php, cakephp

I installed CakePHP 2.4.0 and it appears to be working okay, but when the request finishes I get an internal error that AppModel has been redeclared. The stack trace does not even include any of my code, only cakePHP code. It is something to do with the testing system, which I am not even using. The bug appears in a brand new installation and has apparently been fixed a number of times over the years, and in a number of different ways, but it still happens.

Here are two different reports of this problem, along with the fixes that allegedly fixed it.
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/617

https://github.com/Phally/lazy_model/issues/5

The first solution above was already implemented in cake 2.4.0, but the bug still shows up even with that fix in place. I tried the second solution, but it did not change anything.

Does anyone know a permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: 2.4 is still in beta, is it not? You'll want the latest 2.3.* stable version, I think 2.3.9 at the moment.

Comment: 2.4.0 stable has been released on the 30th of august ! :) as for the initial question, I have upgraded one of my apps to 2.4.0 and it works like a charm *after I upgraded some plugins like DebugKit*. If you use plugins, even for Cake 2.X, there could be some compatibility problems.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your models to make sure you have the following in the top of your model that is extending AppModel.

`App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');`

This means the top of your model should look something like:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class MyModel extends AppModel {
```